# What is ear wax?

Tags: human-ear

A human, at some time in life or the other, must clear the auditory canal. This is usually achieved using soft-cotton buds, or such similar device.

Where does this wax come from? What purpose does it serve? Is it really wax? Is it the inner fluid leaking out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As quoted from the [wikipedia page on Earwax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear_wax):

> Cerumen [earwax] is produced in the outer third of the cartilaginous portion of
>   the human ear canal. It is a mixture of viscous secretions from
>   sebaceous glands and less-viscous ones from modified apocrine sweat
>   glands. The primary components of earwax are shed layers of skin,
>   with 60% of the earwax consisting of keratin, 12–20% saturated and
>   unsaturated long-chain fatty acids, alcohols, squalene and 6–9%
>   cholesterol.

It's purpose -- further quoted -- is that it:

> protects the skin of the human ear canal, assists in cleaning and
>   lubrication, and also provides some protection from bacteria, fungi,
>   insects and water

Some interesting (and stomach churning) earwax trivia:

- In medieval times earwax, and other substances such as urine, were
  used to prepare pigments used by scribes to illustrate illuminated
  manuscripts.
- The 1832 edition of the American Frugal Housewife
  said that "nothing was better than earwax to prevent the painful
  effects resulting from a wound by a nail [or] skewer"; and also
  recommended earwax as a remedy for cracked lips.
- Before waxed thread was commonly available seamstresses would use their own earwax
  to stop the cut ends of threads from fraying.

Comment: in case  you want some more nitty gritty details: this boingboing post records some actual TLC of earwax (original link is off line). note the huge squalene/cholesterol ratio.http://boingboing.net/2006/08/08/scientist-analyzes-t.html

Comment: Gnarly! P.S.: Good news:  thanks to the invaluable Archive.org, we can view the original article here: http://web.archive.org/web/20060829233236/http://blog.tenderbutton.com/?p=187